# how to set https for java servlet application

Tags: http, tomcat, servlets, https

I have created a java servlet web application. It's working properly with "http". Now I want to set "https" secured connection to the server. For that, I have configured the things properly in the tomcatserver/conf/server.xml as follows.

```
Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="conf\localhost.jks" keystorePass="xxxx"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

then I have configured the things on web.xml file also as follows.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

when I send a request through postman, I am given following error. 
[image]

here I have attached the request header also.
[image]

how can I solve this?

Comment: Could you please post the full content of the request's header?

Comment: attached to the issue.

Comment: Your request goes to port 8000 while Tomcat is listening on port 8443. Could you please try it again with correct port and post the full content of the request (in text form)?

Comment: thanks. Problem was with the URL. :)